# Why Can't I Consistently Hit Low Notes?

Tags: voice

I'm 15 and have trouble with low notes. I can sing a A1, and the next minute I can only go to a B1.

What is happening to my voice?

Answer (score 8):

Puberty. That's what is happening.

During puberty, your vocal cords are going through a lot of changes which will eventually lead to a much deeper voice for males, and usually a slightly deeper voice for females.

On the way, your body has not yet learnt how to control them at their new size, tension etc (similarly to the way kids get very clumsy each time they have a growth spurt - the mental model of the body does not yet have accurate arm and leg lengths built in) so rather than resonate at exactly the pitch you are expecting, they are being pulled to the tension/shape your muscle memory remembers for that pitch.

Work through it - it will pass, and eventually you will learn the new characteristics of your voice.

Comment: Will the low A come back after the voice has become stable?

Comment: It may, or it may not - everyone is different. Looking after your voice, and having a good vocal coach will make the difference though.

Answer (score 1):

B1 is already pretty low.  Second bass notes for Western choral singing very rarely go even below E2.  So this perceived limitation is not going to cramp your style and you probably can focus on other aspects of your singing to improve.